# Navigate in react router 6 doesn't redirect to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component with logout button. When I click on it, function logout works but doesn't redirect me to login page. Could you explaine me why it happens?

```
const Header = () => {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userName = useSelector(getUserSelector);
    const logout = async () => {
        const res = await axios.delete(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: token,
            },
        });
        if (res.status === 200) {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');

            <Navigate to='/login' />;
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }

    };

    return (
        <header className='header'>
            <Logo className='header__logo' />
            {token && (
                <div className='header__description'>
                    <div className='header__user'>{userName || 'Admin'}</div>
                    <Button
                        className='header__button'
                        buttonName={LOGOUT_BUTTON}
                        onClick={logout}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </header>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return JSX from a callback and expect it to be rendered like this. Use the `useNavigate` hook and do an imperative navigation. If you want to redirect then also specify the `replace` option.

```
const Header = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const userName = useSelector(getUserSelector);

  const logout = async () => {
    const res = await axios.delete(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
      },
    });
    if (res.status === 200) {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');

      navigate("/login", { replace: true });
    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the `Navigate` component. if you want to programmatically navigate there is a hook for that:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
const userName = useSelector(getUserSelector);
const navigate = useNavigate();

const logout = async () => {
  const res = await axios.delete(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
    },
  });
  if (res.status === 200) {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    navigate("/login");
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
};
```